# Virtuemart search by country

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

1. I want search in my product page for country.To search product by
   country. For this i tried to edit the admin panel of virtuemart by
   adding country to it.But, its not showing any dropdown.
2. Added in file- product_edit_information.php

   ```
               <?php $i = 1 - $i; ?>
           <tr class="row<?php echo $i?>">
               <td ><div style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;">
                   <?php echo JText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_COUNTRY') ?></div>
               </td>
               <td colspan="3">

                   <select name="mprices[product_currency][0]" id="mpricesproduct_currency0" style="display: none;" class="chzn-done">

                       <option><?php echo $this->product->product_url; ?></option>
                   </select>
               </td>
           </tr>
   ```
3. But, no effect on the admin panel. See the screenshot below:
   [image]
4. Also, if possible can anybody suggest a component or module or plugin for coupon system without premium.

Comment: Any help will be of great help to me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any body here to help me to get out of this problem/